# How do you handle exceptional cases

Tags: language-agnostic

This is often situation, but here is latest example:

Companies have various contact data (addresses, phone numbers, e-mails...) when they make job ad, they have checkboxes where they choose how they want to be contacted. It is basically descriptive data. User when reading an ad sees something like "You can apply by mail, in person...", *except* if it's "through web portal" or "by e-mail" because then appropriate buttons should appear. These options are stored in database, and client (owner of the site, not company making an ad) can change them (e.g. they can add "by telepathy" or whatever), yet if they tamper with "e-mail" and "web-portal" options, they screw their web site.

So how should I handle data where everything behaves same way except "this thing" that behaves this way, and "that thing" that behaves some other way, and data itself is live should be editable by client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question as "language-agnostic", and not all languages cleanly support polymorphism, but that's the way I would approach this.

Each option has some type, and different types require different properties to be set. However, every type supports some sort of "render" method that can display the contact method as needed. Since the properties (phone number, or web address, etc.) are type-specific, you can validate the administrator's input when creating these "objects", to make sure that the necessary data is provided and valid. Since you implement the render method, rather than spitting out HTML provided by a user, you can ensure that the rendered page is correct. It's less flexible, but safer and more user friendly.

In the database, you can have one sparsely populated table that holds data for all types of contacts, or a "parent" table with common properties and sub-tables with type-specific properties. It depends on how many types you have and how different they are. In either case, you would have some sort of type indicator, so that you know the type of object to which the data should be be bound.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think twice do you really need it. Reason is simple. You are supposed to serve specific need and input data is a mean to provide that service. If data does not fit with existing service then what is its value and who are consumer of that specific information?

There are two possible answers: You are expanding your client base or you need to change existing service because of change of demand. In both cases you need to star from development of business model. If you describe what service you need and what information it should provide you will avoid much of specific data and come with clear requirements easy to implement in software.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [resolution pattern](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/advanced-table-design-resolutions.html) for this, based on the mention of a database. The link above describes it, but it's actually a lot simpler than it sounds. You write a database query that returns all the possible options (for example, you read the standard options and the customized options together using perhaps a UNION or a JOIN depending on your schema) - the COALESCE SQL keyword is then useful to find the first 'resolution' of the option value that isn't NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all it is is that you have two options that are special, and then anything else is dealt with in the same way, then store your options as strings, and if either of the two special ones appears in that list, then show the appropriate stuff for that special item.

Just check your list of items for the two special ones. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

By writing a very simple [Rules Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93147/how-to-design-a-rule-engine).  You can use an out-of-the box implementation, or you can roll your own.  Since your case seems so simple, I tend to roll my own, because it means less dependencies (YMMV).